# ruby return array of values that exist in every nested array

Tags: arrays, ruby, metaprogramming

I want to build a ruby function that finds the in-common elements of ALL nested arrays. For instance, given the following arrays, this is the answer it would come up with...

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [2]]
=> [2]

[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
=> [1, 2]
```

I could do,

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [2]]
arr[0] & arr[1] & arr[2]
=> [2]
```

But not sure how to make that operation dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka [`#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)) method. This performs aggregate calculations over an enumerable like an array. If you don't pass it an initial value, it will use the first element of the collection as the initial value.

```
arr.reduce { |a, b| a & b } # => [2]
```

And there's a convenient shorthand for this type of expression:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [2]].reduce(:&) # => [2]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]].reduce(:&)   # => [1, 2]
[[1], [2]].reduce(:&)               # => []
[].reduce(:&)                       # => nil
```